# PHP MYSQL query data between date and time fields HEROKU

Tags: php, mysql, heroku, cleardb

i have to query data in certain range of date and time. I have a ClearDB database in heroku with 2 fields to save date and time, these fiels are varchar type, not DATE.
[Data Structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm4Jo.png) and don't look the field names, i have changed below in the querys for better understanding.

I have this query that works:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT dates, times, lat, long, ide FROM data 
WHERE ide = 'lcg1234' AND (dates>= '2016-01-27' AND times>='15:00:00') 
 AND (dates<= '2016-01-29' AND times<='16:00:00') 
 ORDER BY times ASC
```

The problem is when i change the time in the last AND to a lower value like this:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT dates, times, lat, long, ide FROM data 
WHERE ide = 'lcg1234' AND (dates>= '2016-01-27' AND times>='15:00:00') 
AND (dates<= '2016-01-29' AND times<='01:00:00') 
ORDER BY times ASC
```

It not work, why this happend? any ideas are wellcome! and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What is the error that you get? What isn't working?

Comment: Is it data issue? is data present for that query?

Comment: The error is when i query for data between 2016-01-27 at 15:00:00 and 2016-01-29 at 01:00:00 not return any data, it look like the time is not considered here, when i query for data between 2016-01-27 at 15:00:00 and 2016-01-29 at 23:00:00 this return my data.... why?

Answer (score 0):

You should combine dates and times column and make custom date time field. And then make comparisons.

Check if following query works.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT dates, times, lat, long, ide FROM data 
WHERE ide = 'lcg1234' 
AND CONCAT(`dates`,' ',`times`) >= '2016-01-27 15:00:00' 
AND CONCAT(`dates`,' ',`times`) <= '2016-01-29 01:00:00'
ORDER BY times ASC
```

Comment: I have data for this, the error is when i query for data between 2016-01-27 at 15:00:00 and 2016-01-29 at 01:00:00 not return any data, it looks like the second parameter of  time is not considered here, when i query for data between 2016-01-27 at 15:00:00 and 2016-01-29 at 23:00:00 this works and return my data just changing the hour from 01:00:00 to 23:00:00.... why?